# Synonym for plug-in?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, synonyms, programming

I'm making some software which allows users to enable extra features. These extra features are currently called 'plug-ins'.

I'm not a fan of 'plug-in' because of its technical connotations. I also find 'plug-in' unattractive as a word. Can anyone think of an alternative?

Comment: extension, module, package, addon, dll (dynamically linked library), so (shared object), dlc (downloadable content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatives:

modules
expansion or "expansion pack"
extensions
add-ons

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by a *plugin*, in your context.

An *optional feature* is just that - a user/customer *option*, *setting*, or *preference*. Other kinds of plugins are sometimes referred to as *add-ons*.

Find out what term the people you are communicating with use for the thingie - what they are likely to expect and understand, and use that term - whether or not you are a fan of it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not *[extras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extras)* or *[xtras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra)*?

Computing: Xtra (ISP), an Internet service provider;
Xtra (Macromedia), a software plug-in;

Answer (score 0):

The right term depends on the size and nature of your features. Definitions vary depending on the context and audience, so if you want to avoid confusion you shouldn't just choose a term because it sounds better. Unfortunately (fortunately for you?) a lot of terms aren't that well defined and you may get away with choosing whatever sounds nicest to you.

In the context of software development, the terms *module*, *component* or even *service* are sometimes used interchangeably. Those terms are probably confusing for a non-technical audience.

A *plugin-in* is a special kind of component though. Its presence is optional and it extends the application at runtime (i.e. you plug it into a running system). A plug-in usually has a well defined interface which is used for interaction with the core application. If you can't "unplug" a feature by removing it completely from the system, I wouldn't call it a plug-in.

If the features are an integral part of the application that can be enabled and disabled, you could call them just *feature* or *optional feature*.

The latest trend seems to be that any kind of extension is called an "app", which can be downloaded and installed through the applications integrated app store.